# Create a subquery and display values

Tags: sql

I need help creating a query.
I currently have two queries,

1. to count all medals won during the Summer Olympics,
2. to count medals won only by the USA and URS.

```
--The sum of medals won by all nations at the Summer Olympics
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM default.athlete_events_5_csv
WHERE Year BETWEEN 1952 AND 1988
AND Medal <> "NA"
AND Season = 'Summer'
GROUP BY Year
ORDER BY Year

--The sum of medals won by URS and USA at the Summer Olympics
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM default.athlete_events_5_csv
WHERE Year BETWEEN 1952 AND 1988
AND Medal <> "NA"
AND Season = 'Summer'
AND NOC IN ('URS', 'USA')
GROUP BY Year
ORDER BY Year
```

I wanted to use a subquery and finally get the result below with adding the ratio value for earned medals.
But still having difficulties.

```
SELECT Year, Total_medals_number, Medals_USA_and_URS, Total_medals_number/Medals_USA_and_URS
...
GROUP BY Year
ORDER BY Year
```

Please help

Comment: First problem - you don't even have year in your two queries.  And there is no need to do this with two queries, derived tables, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `sum` a conditional `case expression`,

```
SELECT Year, COUNT(*) as Total_medals_number,
  sum(case when NOC IN ('URS', 'USA') then 1 else 0 end) as Medals_USA_and_URS,
  count(*)/sum(case when NOC IN ('URS', 'USA') then 1 else 0 end) as Ratio
FROM default.athlete_events_5_csv
WHERE Year BETWEEN 1952 AND 1988
AND Medal <> "NA"
AND Season = 'Summer'
GROUP BY Year
ORDER BY Year
```